# Ubuntu 15.10 User login stuck

Tags: login, xfce, 15.10

Ubuntu 15.10 fairly fresh install, few changes (nothing major) with a few user accounts.

I noticed that the wallpaper with My company logo was showing as the log on screen for all users, it used to be an xfce one.  I have other users and did not want that, so before I logged off for the night I changed the login screen back, from "none" to "xfce", in the "Session and Startup" app (the one with the gray background and the little mouse).

When I got up this morning, and started the computer, once again my company logo appeared, with the user login box.  So I tried to log in as my company, type in my password, hit enter, then it shows the gray background with the mouse flickering on and off at random with the cursor I get when something is busy or loading.  It stays stuck there and does not change until I reboot.

I had it set to xfce after installing the OS originally, and never changed it to "none" by myself, it was changed somehow without my knowing (I have a few accounts but am the only flesh and blood user).

Luckily I am logged into another account so I can ask for help on how to remedy the situation.  Somehow I need to make changes to the affected account from this one (administrator), so I can log on to it again.

I am Linux syntax and component illiterate, so a step by step solution would be best, and thanks for helping.

Comment: Just in case you are thinking it:  I do not have an Nvidia card.

Comment: Can someone at least point me in the right direction?  I have spent all day trying to find answers.  I have read that it may be a problem with lightdm, but one article points out that it gets bypassed when "user account control" is enabled, which it is on my system.  The article does not go into that scenario, and I can not find anything else about it so far.   Help Pleeeeeeeeeeese!

Comment: More info:  by accident, after trying "recovery options"  on return to the login screen I was warned that without a reboot my graphics may not work.  I logged in anyhow, and sure enough It worked at 640x480 stretched across my 1920x1080 monitor.  I still can not log into that account normally, but it gave me a clue:  I set Cairo Dock (Open GL) to run on start up.  I have an AMD ATI Radeon, but did not install the AMD drivers yet  because they hosed my system before, and I had to reinstall the OS.  Now I will look into installing the drivers without hosing my PC (pointers are welcome).

Comment: Well that went south, there are no proprietary drivers for my GPU, but it is supported by Ubuntu 15.10, so either the problem is not related after all, or I need to do something to make it work right.  There are no advanced tools for any hardware in the GUI, so I am helpless in the matter for now.

Answer (score -1):

I was on my laptop in Ubuntu when a window popped up asking to upgrade to 15.10.  I clicked on it and the download started.  I did not watch it download and when I saw it later, I can not get to the home page.  What I get to is a request in the upper left corner:  owner-Latitude - 5400 loginin:  (Is there a way to bypass this to get to a home page?  If not, how does one delete 15.10?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: -1 because this doesn't seem to be an answer. You might want to post this as [new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) instead.